# Can ASP.NET Web API OData Return Non-Collection Properties?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have the following class:

```
    public class WeeklyReport
    {
        public IEnumerable<DailyReport> DailyReports { get; set; }

        public int? TotalReport
        {
            get
            {
                return DailyReports.Sum(x => x.ReportId);
            }
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return "Weekly Report";
            }
        }
    }

    public class DailyReport
    {
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string ReportTo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Collection { get; set; }
        public int? Leads { get; set; }
    }
```

In one of my method in OData controller, I return IQueryable of WeeklyReport.
However, when the OData endpoint is queried, the returned JSON looks something like:

```
{
"odata.metadata": "http://localhost:546/odata/$metadata#WeeklyReports",
"value": [
    {
        "DailyReports": [
            {
                "Office": "002",
                "Name": "First Last",
                "Type": 10,
                "ReportTo": "00002",
                "Collection": "2014-03-18T00:00:00",
                "Leads": null
            },
            {
                "Office": "002",
                "Name": "Agent, ",
                "Type": 10,
                "ReportTo": "00002",
                "Collection": "2014-03-18T00:00:00",
                "Leads": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DailyReports": [
            {
                "Office": "002",
                "Name": "First Last",
                "Type": 10,
                "ReportTo": "00002",
                "Collection": "2014-03-18T00:00:00",
                "Leads": null
            },
            {
                "Office": "002",
                "Name": "Agent, ",
                "Type": 10,
                "ReportTo": "00002",
                "Collection": "2014-03-18T00:00:00",
                "Leads": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to set ASP.NET Web API OData to return WeeklyReport.TotalReport and WeeklyReport.Title as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the issue. I believe you are using ODataConventionModelBuilder to build the Edm model. By default the builder only adds properties with public get and set to the Edm model. After I add a no-op set and the problem is resolved. you may have a try.

```
public class WeeklyReport
{
    public IEnumerable<DailyReport> DailyReports { get; set; }

    public int? TotalReport
    {
        get
        {
            return DailyReports.Sum(x => x.ReportId);
        }
        set{}
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return "Weekly Report";
        }
        set{}
    }
}
```